# Year.Quarter to Quarter in R- error in as.yearqtr

Tags: r, date

```
> str(qtr)
num 2016

> qtr
[1] 2016.4

> format(as.yearqtr(qtr,"%Y.q"),"Q%q")
[1] "Q2"
```

Shouldn't I get "Q4" instead of "Q2"? Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works, may be easier:

```
library(zoo)

qtr=2016.4
as.yearqtr(toString(qtr), format="%Y.%q")

[1]"2016 Q4"
```

Answer (score 3):

The input to `zoo::as.yearqtr()` is decimal years.

Try this:

```
library(zoo)
x <- 2106 + (0:11)/12
as.yearqtr(x)
 [1] "2106 Q1" "2106 Q1" "2106 Q1" "2106 Q2" "2106 Q2" "2106 Q2" "2106 Q3" "2106 Q3"
 [9] "2106 Q3" "2106 Q4" "2106 Q4" "2106 Q4"
```

or:

```
x <- 2106 + (0:3)/4

x
[1] 2106.00 2106.25 2106.50 2106.75

as.yearqtr(x)
[1] "2106 Q1" "2106 Q2" "2106 Q3" "2106 Q4"
```

Comment: I watched "Back to the Future" recently. :-)

Comment: @Andrie Thanks for the quick reply, but qtr is random and so I think this wouldn't work. i think you are modifying the input to get the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: @Meesha I'm not modifying the input. I'm demonstrating how `as.yearqtr()` works. It takes decimal input. So `2016.4` refers to the 0.4 of the year, i.e. around April, which is in Q2. So the function behaves as expected.